# Choosing a textBox to be edited from GUI (WinForms)

Tags: c#, combobox, textbox

Let's say I have 10 textBoxes in my form. They are named `textBox1, textBox2 etc.` And I'd like to be able to choose the textBox I want to edit - for example I have a `comboBox with numers 1-10` and if I pick, let's say `"5"`, then the text of the textBox5 is being changed (typed in an additional, eleventh, textBox for example).

I know it sounds weird but I need to learn how to choose controls and edit them from the GUI.

Comment: By "the GUI" do you mean Visual Studio's Form editor?

Comment: No, I mean the running app.

Comment: show what you have tried :)

Comment: What do you mean with **being changed (typed in an additional, eleventh, textBox for example** ?

Comment: I got 10 textBoxes and I want to choose one to edit its text. So I pick a proper number from a comboBox (e.g. 5) . And in eleventh textBox I type some text, press a button and  textBox5.Text = stuff that I wrote in this eleventh one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the combobox (`cmb` in my code) [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx),

```
 private void cmb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {  
    var numberFromComboBox = cmb.Text;
    var txtBoxToEdit = Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                               .Where(c => c.Name.EndsWith(numberFromComboBox))
                               .FirstOrDefault();

    if(txtBoxToEdit != null)
    {
      txtBoxToEdit.Text = "was selected";
    }
}
```

**Update**
To understand what the code does, one needs to understand a bit of Linq.

All Controls (ComboBoxes, DataGridViews, TextBoxes, etc.) are stored in the `Controls` collection.

But we only want the TextBoxe's that is directly on the form:

```
List<TextBox> listOfTxtBox = Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
```

This `listOfTextBox` now contains all the textboxes. But we only need one that matches the number we selected in the combobox (`cmb`).

To do that, we "filter" our collection of textboxes with the `Where` method.
In my expression it starts with - `c => c.Name.EndsWith(numberFromComboBox)` gives all the Textboxes that has a name (`TextBox.Name`) that ends with the number from our ComboBox.

The Last part is `FirstOrDefault()`, it simply takes the *first* item in our (now filtred) collection. If there is no items in the collection (for whatever reason) `FirstOrDefault` will return `null`

Hopes this helps to clearfi what the code does

Comment: @user2382010 does this meet your requirements?

Comment: Thanks man, that's EXACTLY what I needed! Now I need to understand how it works :)

Comment: @user2382010 I'll break it down for you - see me edit in a minute

Comment: Ok, now I understand it. Thank you very much!